# Split very long number into six digit groups in separate cells

Tags: excel

423922479012375513457178457180550138521841520952496604498873488994376453521835559200448165554637498872457131510199376418546010374080492305457150455175473104455027541303457131512688454657473104448381453997477124499977406669541303375513490137467744460072532000492113454659402360422309528706455229453997375287375205404307422865375288528497547685445471533317543758522100377090491889524347364876492562454713532610477571550018492113476326403571354101377662432466457108540287544990374720522661431462550028539028434388489113495000402360404307522832548659490117548659552057542216534207470720492312510199527500457153477572402360402360465549408089494011431462376045490117556002541123552297548234406669461755451161469724374720521319436774354059490137376689417359354101440752422184427367490117402385457142549852372653523624522660405547376669462845376702489113521319523982458016550018456997376702552488552072549167490137454828376703457143457180547386442315457134552057376661376660432264371695552057526624457128403018490136548904521892375802490136402730522660540445464995479012531117490138490136377616544204542526533858540444522175457104548904376315364878548719467297457146540287550018490117544895541282477997374416510021552305496604

What function would split it into six digits codes?
I mean break after each six characters to a column.

Comment: On [SO] you are expected to show some effort in solving your problem, then show you working when you get struck. What have you tried so far?

Comment: trying some splitting functions i found - with left and right ...

Comment: tried also replacing spaces to ::: or other type of space - diod't worked too

Comment: Im begginer but im really strugling with it Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Input that huge number as a string into a cell, say A1.

Create a column of numbers (1, 7, 13, ... , 1213) by setting 1 and incrementing by 6. Say this column is in the range B3:B205.

Now make another column using the function =MID($A$1,$B3,6) at cell C3 and dragging C3 through to C205.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) but a native worksheet function will do.

With that very large in A1 as a text string, put this into A2,

```
=mid($A1, (column(A:A)-1)*6+1, 6)
```

Fill right as necessary to get all values. Looks like column GU.

[image: Split on every 6 digits]

Comment: bro it throw out only first digist

Comment: isn't there a function to "break" after each number of digits?> by break i mean start another rows?

Comment: As you can see from my supplied image it does work. I don't make this stuff up.You asked to 'break after each 6 characters to a column and going on' and that is what I thought I gave you. Yes, there is a command to do what you want. Text-to-Columns. However, you will have to manually set 203 breakpoints so I did not think that was an option. So far, you've supplied no original effort or even expected results. Just one very large number pasted into a paragraph with a request for the function.